# Up/down buttons using scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript

The highlited text appears randomly on the page. It is necessary to move between highlited parts using Up/Down buttons. But in my example the buttons lagging on pressing on them when the page comes to the last part of the highlited text and to the first part. Can you help to solve it?

2 buttons:

```
  <button class="button" onclick="up()"><Up</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="down()">Down</button>
```

And their functions:

```
  function scrollIntoView(index){
   let node=document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll")[index];
   if(node){
       node.scrollIntoView();
   }
  };

  function down(){
      if(current > document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll").length){
        current = document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll").length;
        scrollIntoView(current);
      } else if(current == document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll").length){
        scrollIntoView(current);
      } else {
        scrollIntoView(current++);
      }
  };
  function up(){
      if(current < 0){
        current = 0;
        scrollIntoView(current);
      } else if(current == 0){
        scrollIntoView(current);
      } else if(current == document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll").length){
        scrollIntoView(current--);
      } else {
        scrollIntoView(current--);
      }
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the entire HTML page?
Also, I see lots of calls to ``document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll")``. You might want to externalise it so it gets called only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, getting elements by selector is not such a fast operation, so you should probably cache the list. If highlighted parts change, then you need to update the list in a lazy way. For example:

```
let highlightedParts = null;
// fetch the highlighted part list only when needed
function getHiglightedParts() {
    if(highlightedParts == null)
        highlightedParts = document.querySelectorAll(".change_scroll");
    return highlightedParts;
}
// If you change what parts are highlighted, reset to list to null and it will be updated when needed
function highlightedPartsChanged() {
    highlightedParts = null;
}
```

Now you probably want for the search to be looping around. That's quite possible. Let's consider this helper class that will wrap the search around from zero to end and back:

```
class ElementLooper {
  /**
   * @param {function():HTMLElementCollection} elementsProvider
   *
  **/
  constructor(elementsProvider) {
    // this callback provides the element list
    this.getElements = elementsProvider;
    this.index = 0;
  }
  /**
   * @returns {HTMLElement}
   **/
  get nextElement() {
    this.index++;
    // Wrap back to zero
    if(this.index >= this.length) {
      this.index = 0;
    }
    return this.currentElement;
  }
  get previousElement() {
    this.index--;
    // Wrap back to last element
    if(this.index < 0) {
      this.index = this.length - 1;
    }
    return this.currentElement;
  }
  get currentElement() {
    if(this.index >= 0 && this.index < this.length) {
      return this.getElements()[this.index];
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  get length() {
    return this.getElements().length;
  }
}
```

Functioning example:

```js
class ElementLooper {
  /**
   * @param {function():HTMLElementCollection} elementsProvider
   *
  **/
  constructor(elementsProvider) {
    // this callback provides the element list
    this.getElements = elementsProvider;
    this.index = 0;
  }
  /**
   * @returns {HTMLElement}
   **/
  get nextElement() {
    this.index++;
    // Wrap back to zero
    if(this.index >= this.length) {
      this.index = 0;
    }
    return this.currentElement;
  }
  get previousElement() {
    this.index--;
    // Wrap back to last element
    if(this.index < 0) {
      this.index = this.length - 1;
    }
    return this.currentElement;
  }
  get currentElement() {
    if(this.index >= 0 && this.index < this.length) {
      return this.getElements()[this.index];
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  get length() {
    return this.getElements().length;
  }
}
// Create a looper that uses our callback for elements
const looper = new ElementLooper(getHiglightedParts);

function down(){
    if(looper.currentElement)
        looper.currentElement.classList.remove("active");
    const next = looper.nextElement;
    if(next) {
        next.classList.add("active")
        next.scrollIntoView();
    }
};
function up(){
    if(looper.currentElement)
        looper.currentElement.classList.remove("active");
    const previous = looper.previousElement;
    if(previous) {
        previous.classList.add("active")
        previous.scrollIntoView();
    }
};
window.up = up;
window.down = down;

let highlightedParts = null;
// fetch the highlighted part list only when needed
function getHiglightedParts() {
    if(highlightedParts == null)
        highlightedParts = document.querySelectorAll(".highlight");
    return highlightedParts;
}
// If you change what parts are highlighted, reset to list to null and it will be updated when needed
function highlightedPartsChanged() {
    highlightedParts = null;
}
```

```css
html {
background-color: black;
}
#text {
  max-width: 12em;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
.highlight.active {
  background-color: orange
}
button {
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="up()">UP</button>
<button type="button" onclick="down()" style="right:30px;">DOWN</button>
<div id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="highlight">consectetur adipiscing elit</span>. Morbi et justo at justo tempor viverra vitae vitae leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis nec dictum elit. Pellentesque volutpat, purus nec pellentesque <span class="highlight">ullamcorper</span>, sapien arcu maximus purus, ut scelerisque odio felis eget purus. Proin dignissim rutrum velit id suscipit. Aliquam pellentesque tristique tortor a eleifend. Mauris auctor mauris justo, at tincidunt lorem facilisis vitae. Sed faucibus lacus et elit varius, nec tincidunt dolor tempor. Sed urna orci, viverra id scelerisque non, efficitur et elit.

Cras et est suscipit, <span class="highlight">rutrum purus in</span>, accumsan mauris. Etiam ultricies, leo eu rhoncus sagittis, felis turpis porttitor dolor, vel luctus tortor turpis non nisl. Aenean vitae massa at libero imperdiet fermentum. Duis porttitor feugiat interdum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus aliquet laoreet massa. Nulla facilisi. Praesent sed purus nec augue placerat consectetur. <span class="highlight">Maecenas elementum enim non elit sagittis</span>, vel imperdiet ligula malesuada. Ut vel placerat sapien. Duis turpis justo, pulvinar fermentum velit et, semper vehicula neque. <span class="highlight">Pellentesque habitant</span> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam at dictum magna. Etiam elit tortor, euismod sed pulvinar mollis, dictum eget erat.

<span class="highlight">Donec posuere magna odio</span>, nec suscipit tellus venenatis eu. Nunc eros erat, elementum et facilisis mattis, tristique nec dolor. Morbi rutrum mauris vitae fringilla euismod. <span class="highlight">Maecenas sit amet auctor purus.</span> Vivamus dapibus consequat lorem nec posuere. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. <span class="highlight">Curabitur consequat</span> dapibus rhoncus. Pellentesque consequat dolor vel accumsan <span class="highlight">molestie</span>. Suspendisse viverra consectetur eros. In sed massa sapien. Vestibulum rutrum orci quis lorem euismod, vitae semper velit facilisis. <span class="highlight">Ut luctus sapien a luctus</span> posuere. Phasellus sit amet viverra nisl, vitae vulputate augue. Curabitur laoreet diam eget dapibus fermentum. Pellentesque tempus euismod porttitor.

Quisque non quam laoreet, <span class="highlight">venenatis</span> neque eu, eleifend nisl. Aliquam ac neque tempor, sagittis erat eget, sagittis orci. Sed interdum massa vel urna egestas mollis. Mauris turpis metus, interdum id ullamcorper venenatis, <span class="highlight">vestibulum at sem</span>. Duis tellus eros, scelerisque ac pellentesque sit amet, feugiat in leo. Phasellus faucibus fermentum nisi. Vivamus a ullamcorper ex.

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Tomáš, one more question: the text appears on the page through 'document.getElementById('outputdiv').innerHTML' so the first time everything works fine. But it seems to be that next time class 'ElementLooper' should be reset. How it can be done?

Comment: It says there in the answer: you should call `highlightedPartsChanged()` when the list changes (such as when you reset the entire innerHTML). That will set the cached list to null and force it to be generated again the next time you click "next".

Comment: Note I did a small change to `up` and `down` to avoid errors when `currentElement` is null. Note that if the answer works for you, you can mark it as "Accepted" so other people know you already have an answer. It also gives you 2 points of reputation.